# How to enumerate folder contents in Oct 2018

Tags: c++-winrt

Trying to translate to cppwinrt the StorageFolder method GetFilesAsync I'm unable to get past compiler link errors. Here is a very simple routine to test the concept:

```cpp
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.h" 
#include "winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h"
IAsyncAction TestClass::LoadFiles()
{
    StorageFolder appFolder = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current().InstalledLocation(); 
    StorageFolder assetsFolder = co_await appFolder.GetFolderAsync(hstring(L"Assets")); 
    auto files = co_await assetsFolder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery::DefaultQuery); 
}
```

The problem seems to lie in the return type for GetFilesAsync. I've tried various types for that, e.g. IVectorView, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know of a code example showing how this enumeration might be accomplished in C++/winrt?

[UPDATE] Returning to this project with SDK 10.0.17666 and VS 15.9.0 Preview 3 I find that the solution adopted earlier from these answers no longer works. This time I will be sure to include the full error to see if anyone has ideas. For simplicity I'll use just the simple code provided by IInspectable, altered only to make it a class member in my ResourceManager class:

```
 #include "winrt/Windows.ApplicationModel.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.Streams.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.Search.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.UI.Core.h"
#include "pch.h"
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Search;

IAsyncAction ResourceManager::LoadActivities()
{
    StorageFolder appFolder = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current().InstalledLocation();
    StorageFolder assetsFolder = co_await appFolder.GetFolderAsync(L"Activities");
    auto files = co_await assetsFolder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery::DefaultQuery);
}
```

The call to GetFilesAsync now produces the following link error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: struct winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation > __thiscall winrt::impl::consume_Windows_Storage_Search_IStorageFolderQueryOperations::GetFilesAsync(enum winrt::Windows::Storage::Search::CommonFileQuery const &)const " (?GetFilesAsync@?$consume_Windows_Storage_Search_IStorageFolderQueryOperations@UStorageFolder@Storage@Windows@winrt@@@impl@winrt@@QBE?AU?$IAsyncOperation@U?$IVectorView@UStorageFile@Storage@Windows@winrt@@@Collections@Foundation@Windows@winrt@@@Foundation@Windows@3@ABW4CommonFileQuery@Search@Storage@63@@Z) referenced in function "public: struct winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction __thiscall AppEngine::ResourceManager::LoadActivities$_ResumeCoro$2(void)" (?LoadActivities$_ResumeCoro$2@ResourceManager@AppEngine@@QAE?AUIAsyncAction@Foundation@Windows@winrt@@XZ)

(followed by the path to the object file)

I have to admit I find that error message hard to decipher. Perhaps someone else here will have an idea? Must be something that changed in recent system updates.

Comment: Please share the actual errors. Without that information, you're leaving everybody to speculate about what's missing. I suspect you're missing a #include, but that's just an educated guess.

Comment: Also, explicitly constructing an hstring around L"Assets" is unnecessary and actually imposes a slight performance hit.

Comment: Thanks - the error is too long to fit in the comment, so here it's abridged:
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: struct winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<struct winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView<struct winrt::Windows::Storage::StorageFile> > __cdecl winrt::impl::consume_Windows_Storage_Search_IStorageFolderQueryOperations<struct winrt::Windows::Storage::StorageFolder>::GetFilesAsync(enum winrt::Windows::Storage::Search::CommonFileQuery const &)const " (?GetFilesAsync@?

Comment: Don't post vital information in comments. Instead, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48736925/edit) your question and add the error message(s) there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, the following standalone code builds just fine. So you're probably either missing a #include or a link library, but it's impossible to tell when you don't share important information like **what actual error(s) you're seeing**.

```cpp
#pragma comment(lib, "WindowsApp")

#include <winrt/Windows.ApplicationModel.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Search.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Search;

IAsyncAction LoadFiles()
{
    StorageFolder appFolder = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current().InstalledLocation();
    StorageFolder assetsFolder = co_await appFolder.GetFolderAsync(L"Assets");
    auto files = co_await assetsFolder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery::DefaultQuery);
}

int main()
{
    LoadFiles().get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful, Ryan. It appears I was missing just the #include for Storage.Search.h - I had Storage.h but not that. This does compile and run! And I find that the return type is winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView<winrt::Windows::Storage::StorageFile >, so next up is to find out how to deal witih IVectorView. I had actually been hoping this would cast to std::vector<StorageFile>.

Comment: p.s. The only thing about this that doesn't work for me, and hasn't worked when I've used IAsyncAction for other calls, is the .get() method. If I call LoadFiles().get(); for an AsyncAction like that named LoadFiles() I get a crash here :  template <typename Async>
    void blocking_suspend(Async const& async) noexcept
    {
        WINRT_ASSERT(!is_sta());

Comment: .get() blocks the current thread to wait for the result. When you have an app with a UI, you can't block the main/UI thread. That's a good practice in general, and an enforced restriction in WinRT.

The XamlCode sample has a good example of how to use co_await in a coroutine and then have switch back to the UI thread to post its results.

Comment: You can pass std::vector to a method expecting IVectorView as **input**, but that transform doesn't work in reverse - IVectorView's interface is more restrictive than std::vector's. However, C++/WinRT does make it considerably easier to deal with IVectorView. You can get the begin/end iterators to interop with the rest of STL and with range-based for loops.

Comment: So it appears that I should not attempt to use IAsyncAction and .get() in an app with a UI? The XamlCode uses fire_and_forget instead. I can run that without crashing by adapting from the XamlCode sample. The folder I'm trying to enumerate never is found, but I suppose this is some other flaw in my work. I will have to do some more research to find the answers to questions like: how does one know when an async action has completed?

Comment: You can use IAsyncAction and check its status, but you can't use get() because that's the part that blocks. Or, you could simply have a coroutine co_await the action, and continue your work there,  optionally switching to the UI thread if needed.

Comment: Thanks much, Ryan.